# Which code signing certificate should I obtain for an Adobe AIR application (.exe, .dmg, .deb, .rpm)

Tags: air, installation, certificate, code-signing

I need to sign my Adobe AIR application which is a native installer. Right now I just have a Windows version, but soon I'll be porting it to other OSes including mobile OS.

My query is whether I need to get a separate code signing certificate for each one or is one enough? Also does 32-bit and 64-bit matter?

Verisign have categorized certificates for Windows (`.exe`) and Adobe AIR (`.air` and `.airi`) separately. So which one should I obtain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAs selling code signing certificates always pretend that you need different certificates to sign different kinds of applications. This is basically a scam. Most of the time the certificates are exactly the same, only the file format might differ. Even if the file format isn't supported by your code signing tool, there are ways to convert between different formats. So basically it doesn't matter which certificate you buy.

If you package your AIR app with a captive runtime, you can simply use a self-signed certificate with the `adt` tool. It's only important to sign the executable created with `adt` and your installer afterwards. If you create a native installer directly with `adt`, provide your certificate using the code signing options.

Under Windows, you should use Microsoft's `signtool` utility to sign the `.exe` file of your app and your installer if you want to package with a captive runtime. So I'd choose a code signing certificate for Windows. But as I said, it doesn't really matter (and there are cheaper options than Verisign).

Under Mac OS X ("Gatekeeper"), things are a little different. You can only use certificates issued by Apple. You have to enroll in the "Mac Developer Program" ($99 per year) to receive a code signing certificate for OS X. If you use a captive runtime, sign the application bundle created with `adt` using the `codesign` utility. If you create a `.pkg` installer, use the `--sign` option of the `productbuild` tool. There's a similar "iOS Developer Program" for iOS apps.

Under Linux, you don't sign packages with certificates issued by a CA. You simply sign them with a GPG key that you can create yourself for free. You have to publish your public GPG key so your customers can make sure that your packages are valid, though.

For Android apps, you can simply use a self-signed certificate, AFAIK.

32-bit and 64-bit apps can be signed in exactly the same way. You don't need separate certificates. But `adt` will only create 32-bit apps anyway.